# Recover from sudo strip * in /usr/bin

Tags: linux, fedora, system-recovery

I stupidly did `sudo strip *` in `/usr/bin`. Now my computer can’t boot (X fails to load).

What should I do?

Comment: X not loading and failing to boot are very different, can you Ctrl+Alt+F2 to TTY?

Comment: nope. I wound up reinstalling the box (/home is on separate partition, so lost no data).

Comment: This question should be closed because the OP has solved the issue by reinstalling (probably the only solution anyway) and so the question is unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: Others may want to know that reinstalling is the only answer.

Comment: What's wrong with stripped binaries? Why it does not work?

Comment: Some of the program were actually shared libraries, and stripping them made them useless

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way for you to recover would be to reinstall.  You can back up your data (excluding `/usr/bin/`) by booting onto a rescue disk like [System Rescue CD](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage), and mounting your drive.

Theoretically, you would be able to copy the `/usr/bin` directory from another installation, but a reinstall would probably be simpler.

Comment: Did just that. Reinstalling programs now.