# sudo strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5 is there any way to undo this command?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

'"sudo strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5"'
**USED THIS TO RUN DOLPHIN ON WSL2 **

> IS THERE A WAY TO UNDO THIS CODE

Comment: Perhaps [this post](https://superuser.com/q/721690/196634) can help you. Otherwise you should have a way to download the lib somewhere and restore it manually.

Comment: While it's too late for you in this particular instance, I would recommend in the future that you create backups of your WSL instances before doing something like this.  It's fairly straightfoward with `wsl --export` to create the backup and `wsl --import` to test and reimport it.  See `wsl --help` for a full description of the arguments.